# Construct 2's Scroll-to too small?

Tags: sprites, platformer, behavior, construct-2

I'm making a platformer that wants the screen to closely follow the player, and I know I need the Scroll TO behavior.

However, when I tried to make the screen move to the player, I get this:

[image: The player's sprite is too small.]

As seen in the picture, the player's sprite is (I think) too small. Is there any way to increase the 'zoom-ness' of the Scroll-to behavior?

Below is the code's snippet:

[image: The code snippet of the scroll-to.]

Do you know what I have to do, or is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance,

JamieK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ScrollTo` behaviour only moves the camera to the centre of your object.
The *Zoom Level* of a layout can be changed via the `Set Layout Scale` `System` parameter.

**Example:**
[image: On player collison with trigger(0) do Set layout scale 0.5]

Image is a screenshot of [Camera Zoom Tutorial | "Construct 2"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QI1J6WX1d9s)